# If..,else.. in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, if-statement, local-storage

I am trying to solve my problem with if-else in Javascript.
I would highly appreciate your help.

I wanted to filter the name via gender,  also safe the keys - **woman** / **man** to local storage.

But I can not find out how to make if-else clause.

Can someone help me?

There is also the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RNJxbiU_DsFTCqGJWgxpepCgdOhGuzIj/view?usp=sharing

**Thanks a lot, it means world to me, I am new here. :-)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function displayName() {

    let safeNameVal = localStorage.getItem('woman');
    let safeName;

    if (safeNameVal) {
      safeName = JSON.parse(safeNameVal);
    } else {
      safeName = [];
    }

    //find list
    let nameUl = $('#list_2');
    nameUl.empty(); //.html('')

    //making list 
    $.each(safeName, function(key, name) {

      let nameLi = $('<li></li>');
      nameLi.text(name);

      //remove link
      let jmenoRemoveLink = $('<a href="#">x</a>');
      jmenoRemoveLink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //name
        let safeNameVal = localStorage.getItem('woman');
        let safeName;
        if (safeNameVal) {
          safeName = JSON.parse(safeNameVal);
        } else {
          safeName = [];
        }
        //remove
        safeName.splice(key, 1);
        //safe name
        localStorage.setItem('woman', JSON.stringify(safeName));
        //display name
        displayName();
      });

      nameLi.append(jmenoRemoveLink);

      nameUl.append(nameLi);
    });

  }

  $('#formular').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    let zadaneJmeno = $('#name').val();
    if (zadaneJmeno) {
      //safe
      let safeNameVal = localStorage.getItem('woman');
      let safeName;

      if (safeNameVal) {
        safeName = JSON.parse(safeNameVal);
      } else {
        safeName = [];
      }
      safeName.push(zadaneJmeno);

      localStorage.setItem('woman', JSON.stringify(safeName)); /// ["Tom"]

      //list
      displayName();
      $('#name').val('');
    } else {
      // alert
      alert('please enter the name"');
      $('#name').focus();
    }

  });

  $('#removeAll').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('woman', '[]'); ///localStorage.setItem('woman', JSON.stringify([]));
    displayName();
  });


  displayName();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formular">

  <label for="name">Enter the name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" required />
  <label for="section">Gender</label>

  <select name="selectSection" id="section" required>
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="man" id="man">man</option>
    <option value="woman" id="woman">woman</option>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="add" />
</form>

<button id="removeAll">Remove</button>

<div id="man_div">
  <h1>man:</h1>
  <ul id="list"></ul>

</div>


<div id="woman_div">
  <h1>woman:</h1>
  <ul id="list_2"></ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you be clearer on the trouble you are facing? I did not quite understand your problem

Comment: I can't figure out how to split men and women using option value here. I was trying to make if-else statement but it doesn't work.

Currently, if I enter a male or female name, it will appear in "div woman" and also I have a key at local storage only for woman.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know you already have a solution but I offer an alternative, in vanilla Javascript rather than jQuery, that splits the names according to gender - assigns them to individual areas in `localStorage` based upon gender and has the functionality to remove individual items from the store. Any items stored in any of the generated stores will be used to populate the HTML lists on page load. I don't use jQuery which is why I wrote this in plain js - no doubt you can cherrypick things from it that might be useful - I hope that it is useful anyway.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Gender splitter</title>
        <style>
            #lists > div{
                padding:1rem;
                margin:1rem auto;
                border:1px dotted gray;
            }
            .active{
                background:whitesmoke
            }
            h1{text-transform:capitalize}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
          <label>Enter the name
            <input type='text' name='name' required />
          </label>
          <label>Gender
              <select name='selectSection' required>
                <option selected hidden disabled>---
                <option value='male'>Male
                <option value='female'>Female
                <option value='teapot'>Teapot
                <option value='crocodile'>Crocodile
              </select>
          </label>
          <!-- initially disabled to prevent adding when no gender is selected -->
          <input type='submit' value='add' disabled />
        </form>

        <button id='removeAll'>Remove</button>
        <div id='lists'></div>
        
        
        
        
        
        <script>
            const oSelect=document.querySelector('select[name="selectSection"]');
            const oText=document.querySelector('input[name="name"]');
            const oBttn=document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
            const oDelete=document.querySelector('button#removeAll');
            
            
            // generate the necessary HTML nodes to display names/genders based
            // upon the options in the select menu.
            const createlist=function(){
                let parent=document.getElementById('lists');
                oSelect.querySelectorAll('option').forEach( option=>{
                    if( option.value !== oSelect.childNodes[1].value ){
                        let gender=option.value;
                        let div=document.createElement('div');
                            div.id=gender;
                        let h1=document.createElement('h1');
                            h1.textContent=gender;
                        let ul=document.createElement('ul');
                        
                        div.appendChild(h1);
                        div.appendChild(ul);
                        
                        parent.appendChild( div );
                    }
                });
                
                parent.querySelectorAll('div').forEach( div=>{
                    div.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        // delete specific item from the store
                        if( e.target!=e.currentTarget && e.target.tagName=='A') deleteitem( e );
                    });
                    
                    // load any names from the store on page load and recreate the lists
                    let store=div.id;
                    if( localStorage.getItem(store)!=null )JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( store ) ).forEach( name=>{
                        addlistitem(name,store);
                    })
                });
            }
            
            // erase store content by gender and clear html list display
            const clearstoreitems=function(gender){
                localStorage.setItem( gender, JSON.stringify([]) );
                document.querySelector( 'div#' + gender ).querySelector('ul').innerHTML='';
            };
            
            // delete specific item from particular store
            const deleteitem=function(e){
                let parent=e.target.parentNode;
                let name=parent.dataset.name;
                let gender=parent.dataset.gender;
                parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
                
                let data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(gender));
                if( data!=null )data.splice(data.indexOf(name),1);
                
                localStorage.setItem(gender,JSON.stringify(data));
            };
            
            // add new item to HTML list based upon gender
            const addlistitem=function(name,gender){
                let a=document.createElement('a');
                    a.href='#';
                    a.innerHTML='X';            
                let li=document.createElement('li');
                    li.value=name;
                    li.textContent=name;
                    li.dataset.name=name;
                    li.dataset.gender=gender;
                    li.appendChild( a );
                
                document.querySelector( 'div#' + gender ).querySelector('ul').appendChild( li );
            };
            
            // add new name to the localStorage in gender specific named store
            const addstoreitem=function(name,gender){
                let data=localStorage.getItem( gender );
                if( data!=null ){
                    let json=JSON.parse( data );
                        json.push(name);
                    data=JSON.stringify(json);
                } else { data=JSON.stringify([name]); }
                localStorage.setItem( gender, data );
            };
            
            // Add new item listener
            oBttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if( oText.value!='' ){
                    addlistitem(oText.value,oSelect.value);
                    addstoreitem(oText.value,oSelect.value);
                    oText.value='';
                    return true;
                }
                alert('Name please...');
            });
            
            oSelect.addEventListener('change',function(e){
                // ensure the "Add" button is enabled
                if( oBttn.disabled )oBttn.disabled=false;
                document.querySelectorAll('div.active').forEach( div=>{
                    div.classList.remove('active')
                });
                
                // assign a class to visually identify which gender is selected
                document.querySelector( 'div#' + this.value ).classList.add('active')
            });
            
            
            // erase this entire store - reset to empty array
            oDelete.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                clearstoreitems(oSelect.value);
            });
            
            

            
            createlist();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe your version is better for me. Thanks a lot, sir. :-)

Comment: the above can easily be modified to allow for an unlimited number of genders with very little extra code.. I'll update this

Comment: Woud you be so kind... can you explain these lines ?
 oSelect.querySelectorAll('option').forEach( option=>{
      if( option.value !== oSelect.childNodes[1].value ){

Comment: the first option in the `select` menu should not be used in the javascript function as it has no value. It should not be selected anyway due to the `selected hidden disabled` attributes but this line `if( option.value !== oSelect.childNodes[1].value ){` explicitly says "everything but this" as it were..

Comment: is there any way how recreate this app to allow the user make their own category? can you please help me? Thank you so much

Comment: Yes - it is possible to modify this so that a user may add/delete categories and into those categories add new names as before.

Comment: While I was trying to remake your code I was not very successful with the ,, select option", which you use during whole code. Firsly I was trying simply -  to add new input (Entry category) ..and compare the value with the option from the select - then make selectSelection hidden - allow user to use the category only which we have in the html... so when user enter another name of category than - male/female/teapot/crocodile...it shows alert ("You have to enter only :male,famel,teapot,crocodile) but still doesnt work.. do you have any idea how to make it in easier way?

Comment: Your English is better than my Czech but alas I don't quite follow what you mean.

Comment: I have been modifying this code but wish to further understand what it is you are hoping to do.

Comment: check my comment bellow :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227516/discussion-between-professor-abronsius-and-eliska-dolezalova).

Answer (score 0):

I made a number of changes to your script, do note that as I am solving your problem, I removed the 'x' function on click because it is too verbose to read while solving your problem, do add it back later, and make sure you remove from the correct localStorage.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  function displayName() {
    //Separate the local storage into man and woman keys
    let manSafeNameVal = localStorage.getItem('man');
    let manSafeName;

    let womanSafeNameVal = localStorage.getItem('woman');
    let womanSafeName

    if (manSafeNameVal) {
      manSafeName = JSON.parse(manSafeNameVal);
    } else {
      manSafeName = [];
    }

    if (womanSafeNameVal) {
      womanSafeName = JSON.parse(womanSafeNameVal);
    } else {
      womanSafeName = [];
    }

    //find list
    //Use list and list_2 to display
    let manUl = $('#list');
    let womanUl = $('#list_2');
    manUl.empty(); //.html('')
    womanUl.empty();

    //list for man
    $.each(manSafeName, function (key, name) {
      let nameLi = $('<li></li>');
      nameLi.text(name);
      //do add back your 'x' remove here, because it is too verbose to read when I am trying to read the code
      manUl.append(nameLi);
    });

    //list for woman
    $.each(womanSafeName, function (key, name) {
      let nameLi = $('<li></li>');
      nameLi.text(name);
      //Also here, the 'x' for woman list
      womanUl.append(nameLi);
    });

  }

  $('#formular').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    let zadaneJmeno = $('#name').val();
    //get the selected gender, either man or woman
    let gender = $('#section').val();
    console.log(gender);
    console.log(zadaneJmeno);
    if (zadaneJmeno && gender !== "") {
      //safe into the localStorage of selected gender
      let safeNameVal = localStorage.getItem(gender);
      let safeName;

      if (safeNameVal) {
        safeName = JSON.parse(safeNameVal);
      } else {
        safeName = [];
      }

      safeName.push(zadaneJmeno);

      localStorage.setItem(gender, JSON.stringify(safeName));/// ["Tom"]

      //list
      displayName();
      $('#name').val('');

    } else {
      // alert
      alert('please enter the name"');
      $('#name').focus();
    }

  });

  $('#removeAll').click(function () {
    localStorage.setItem('woman', '[]');     ///localStorage.setItem('woman', JSON.stringify([]));
    displayName();
  });


  displayName();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const katText = document.getElementById('txtKategorie');
            
            const oText=document.querySelector('input[homework="homework"]');
            // selektor tlačítka uložit úkol
            const oBttn=document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
            // selektor tlačítka na odstranění všech úkolů z kategorie
            const oDelete=document.querySelector('button#removeAll');
            
 
            const createlist=function(){
                let parent=document.getElementById('lists');

                Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (key) {
                    let category = key;
                    let div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.id = category;
                    let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
                    h1.textContent = category;
                    let ul = document.createElement('ul');

                    div.appendChild(h1);
                    div.appendChild(ul);
                    div.onclick = oznacDiv; 
                    parent.appendChild(div);
                });

                

                parent.querySelectorAll('div').forEach( div=>{
                    div.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        // odstranění určité položky 
                        if( e.target!=e.currentTarget && e.target.tagName=='A') deleteitem( e );
                    });
                    
                    // při načtení stránky načíst úkoly z localStorage a vytvoření listu 
                    // podmmínka -- pokud není úložiště prázdné
                    let store=div.id;
                    if( localStorage.getItem(store)!=null )JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( store ) ).forEach( homework=>{
                        addlistitem(homework,store);
                    })
                });
            }

            //na klik oznaci div
            function oznacDiv() {
                if (oBttn.disabled) oBttn.disabled = false;
                document.querySelectorAll('div.active').forEach(div => {
                    div.classList.remove('active')
                });
              
                document.querySelector('div#' + this.id).classList.add('active')
            }
            

            
            const clearstoreitems=function(category){
                localStorage.setItem( category, JSON.stringify([]) );
                document.querySelector( 'div#' + category ).querySelector('ul').innerHTML='';
            };
            
            
            
            
    
            
            
            const deleteitem=function(e){
                let parent=e.target.parentNode;
                let homework=parent.dataset.homework;
                let category=parent.dataset.category;
                parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
                
                let data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(category));
                if( data!=null )data.splice(data.indexOf(homework),1);
                
                localStorage.setItem(category,JSON.stringify(data));
            };
            
            
            
            
            
            

            const addlistitem=function(homework,category){
                let p=document.createElement('button');
                   
                    p.innerHTML='  Uprava';
                    p.onclick =function(){ 
                                   editWorking(li);             
                    }
                
                let a=document.createElement('a');
                    a.href='#';
                    a.innerHTML='  Hotovo';            
                let li=document.createElement('li');
                    li.value=homework;
                    li.textContent=homework;
                    li.dataset.homework=homework;
                    li.dataset.category=category;
                    li.appendChild( a );
                    li.appendChild(p);
                
                document.querySelector( 'div#' + category ).querySelector('ul').appendChild( li );
            };
            
            

    
              function editWorking(e){
                 let editValue = prompt('Přejete si upravit úkol?', e.firstChild.nodeValue);
                 e.firstChild.nodeValue = editValue; 
                  
                 let parent=e.parentNode;
                 let homework=parent.dataset.homework;
                 let category=parent.dataset.category;
                  
                 addlistitem(editValue,category); 
                 addstoreitem(editValue,category);
                }       
            

            const addstoreitem=function(homework,category){
                let data=localStorage.getItem( category );
                
                if( data!=null ){
                    let json=JSON.parse( data );
                        json.push(homework);
                    data=JSON.stringify(json);
                }
                else 
                { 
                    data=JSON.stringify([homework]); 
                }
                
                localStorage.setItem( category, data );
                
            };
            
            
            
            //prida novej div s kategorii a poznamkou
            const addNewItemList = function () {
                let parent = document.getElementById('lists');
                let category = katText.value;
                        let div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.id = category;
                        let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
                        h1.textContent = category;
                        let ul = document.createElement('ul');
                        div.appendChild(h1);
                div.appendChild(ul);
                div.onclick = oznacDiv; 
                        parent.appendChild(div);
                parent.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
                    div.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        // odstranění určité položky 

                        if (e.target != e.currentTarget && e.target.tagName == 'A') deleteitem(e);
                    });

                    // při načtení stránky načíst úkoly z localStorage a vytvoření listu 
                    // podmmínka -- pokud není úložiště prázdné
                    let store = div.id;
                    if (localStorage.getItem(store) != null) JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(store)).forEach(homework => {
                        addlistitem(homework, store);
                    })
                });
            }

            
            
            
            
            
            oBttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (oText.value != '') {
                    if (katText.value != '') {

                        if (document.querySelector('div#' + katText.value) == null) {
                            addNewItemList()
                        }
                        addlistitem(oText.value, katText.value);
                        addstoreitem(oText.value, katText.value);
                        oText.value = '';
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        alert('Zadejte kategorii prosím...');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Zadejte úkol prosím...');
                }
            });
        
            
            
            
   
           
            
            
            // vymazat, resetovat pole
            oDelete.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                document.querySelectorAll('div.active').forEach(div => {
                    //clearstoreitems(document.querySelectorAll('div.active').id);
                    clearstoreitems(div.id);
                    //div.classList.remove('active')
                });
                
            });
            
            

            
            createlist();
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
*{
    padding: 100;
    margin: 100;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
/**styly pro tělo celé aplikace **/
body{
    background: rgb(131,58,180);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131,58,180,1) 0%, rgba(253,29,29,1) 50%, rgba(252,176,69,1) 100%);
   /* background: linear-gradient(139deg, rgba(193,62,62,1) 0%, rgba(230,179,50,1) 100%); 
    background-image: url("pozadi.png");*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%; 
}


.weather{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    
}



/** pomohla jsem si tady https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ **/
/**
.flex-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
     -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 100 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 100 auto;
    flex: 0 100 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    
    }
**/

/**nadpis aplikace **/
#nadpis {
    /** margin: auto; 
    width: 50%;
    
    padding: 5px; **/
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.predpoved {
/** width: 30%; **/
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    border:4px solid white;
    background: black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 8px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.52); 
                box-shadow: 7px 8px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.52);
    
    
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 10%;
    width:60%;
    padding: 0 auto;
    
    
    
}

.nadpis_1{
    
    font-size: 50px;
    color:white;
    font:bold;

    
}





label{
    color:white;
    font:oblique;
    text-transform:inherit;
    
}


 #lists > div{
                padding:1rem;
                margin:1rem auto;
                border-radius: 15px 50px;
                border:4px solid white;
                margin-left: 30px;
                margin-right: 30px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 8px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.52); 
                box-shadow: 7px 8px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.52);
            }
            .active{
               background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(252,176,69,1) 0%, rgba(253,29,29,1) 50%, rgba(131,58,180,1)100%);
              
                
            }
            h1{
                text-transform:capitalize;
                color:white;
}
            ul{
                list-style: square;

            }
            ul li{

                color:white;
                margin-top: 40px;
                font-size: 20px;

            }
            ul a {

                color:white;
                font:oblique;
                
                padding: 10px;
                margin:10px;
                margin-left:100px;
                border-radius: 15px ;
                border:1px solid white;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;

            }
    ul a:hover {

                color:white;
                font:oblique;
                background:rgba(252,176,69,1);
                padding: 10px;
                margin:10px;
                margin-left:100px;
                border:1px solid white;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;

            }



form{
    
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;

}

#removeAll{
    
    color:white;
    font:oblique;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 15px ;
    border:1px solid white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    
    
}

#removeAll:hover {
    
    color:white;
    font:oblique;
    background: red;                
    border:1px solid white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    
    
}
#refresh{
    
    color:white;
    font:oblique;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 15px ;
    border:1px solid white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    
    
    
}

#refresh:hover {
    
    color:white;
    font:oblique;
    background: red;                
    border:1px solid white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    
    
    
}
#safe{
    
    color:white;
    font:oblique;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 15px ;
    border:1px solid white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    
    
    
}

#safe:hover {
    
    color:white;
    font:oblique;
    background: red;                
    border:1px solid white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Deadline</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
         <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-container">
            
        <div id="nadpis">
        <h1>Deadline</h1>
    
    
        <form>
        
        
            <label for="txtHomework">Your homework.. </label>
            <input type="text" id="txtHomework" homework="homework" required />
          
            
          <label for="txtKategorie">Category</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtKategorie" kategorie="valKategorie" required />
              <!--<select name="selectSection" required>
                <option selected hidden disabled>---</option>
                <option value="škola">Škola</option>
                <option value="Práce">Práce</option>
                <option value="Doma">Doma</option>
                <option value="Jiné">Jiné</option>
                
              </select>-->
          <!--</label>-->
                
          <!-- tlačítko uložit je nedostupné dokud nevybereme kategorii a nezapíšeme úkol -->
          <input id ="safe" type="submit" value="Uložit" />
        </form>

        
        <div id="lists"></div>
        
        <button id="removeAll">Vyčistit kategorii</button>
```